# PHP/Laravel: Using username as url identifier

Tags: php, laravel

In my Application I have this url: domain.com/u/username 
And in the registration form I have these fields: (Full name, email, password) However, How do I generate a temporary user id to use it in the url until my user fills his profile (including his username) so I use it in the url? 
Something like this: domain.com/u/43r33-q23r4
So, If the user selected his username then it will be used in the url, Otherwise the unique identifier (ex: 23r43-34t4y) will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add **UUID column** and use UUID package to auto generate it when the user register then you can check by username or UUID column

Comment: Well, One more question, Is UUID generated automatically?

Comment: yes, you can find one generated auto by making some setting first

Comment: Yes, I did make it already, Thanks for the answer.. I found this laravel package that can help to do that automatically .. https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid